# Practical Use Cases of UDFs (ITVF and MTVF)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm studying for `exam 70-461 Querying SQL Server 2012`, on the chapter `UDF`. Some functions are similar as to the results, and searching on internet I did not find any practice explanation about when to use `ITVF (Inline Table-Valued Function)` or `MTVF (Multi-statement Table Valued Function)`.

Anybody can help me, explaining the difference in when to use each one?

Answer (score 0):

Inline functions contain a single `select` query, which you specify in the `return` statement. They are usually preferred over multi-statement UDFs, since SQL Server can incorporate the inner query into the overall execution plan.

As such, there are only 2 cases when you might want to use multi-statement UDFs:

1. The required output cannot be efficiently produced using a single `select` statement;
2. Query optimizer "misses" with query integration, producing less efficient plan than if you use multi-statement UDF or cached rowset. Such cases are rare, but still a possibility.